# Error al compilar Java tras modificar archivo

Tags: java

Estoy modificando un archivo *.java*:

[image: Listado de ficheros java]

Cuando he modificado el archivo lo guardo, pero al compilar me saltan muchos errores:

```
            Notification notification = Main.db.getNotification(notificationId);
            ^
  symbol:   class Notification
  location: class WebServer
src/java/principal/WebServer.java:49: error: cannot find symbol
            Client client = Main.db.getClient(notification.getClient_dni());
            ^
  symbol:   class Client
  location: class WebServer
```

Todos los archivos y directorios se encuentran aquí:

[image: Ruta de archivos]

El codigo del archivo en cuestión es este

```
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer;

import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class WebServer {
    static final int port = 8081;
    static final String newLine = "\r\n";

    public void start() {

        try {
            HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(port), 0);

            server.createContext("/openNotification/", httpExchange ->
            {
                getHandler(httpExchange.getRequestURI().toString());

                byte response[] = "Done".getBytes("UTF-8");

                httpExchange.getResponseHeaders().add("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=UTF-8");
                httpExchange.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.length);

                OutputStream out = httpExchange.getResponseBody();
                out.write(response);
                out.close();
            });

            server.start();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(WebServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    private void getHandler(String getParameters) {

        try {
            System.out.println("PETICIÓN: " + getParameters);
            int notificationId = Integer.parseInt(getParameters.split("/")[2]);

            Notification notification = Main.db.getNotification(notificationId);
            notification.setUrl("https://ws020.juntadeandalucia.es/notificaciones/snja/OpenNotificacion.do?ID=" + notificationId);
            Client client = Main.db.getClient(notification.getClient_dni());

            String cookies = Main.getSessionCookie(client, client.getCertificateFile().getAbsolutePath(), client.getCertificatePassword());

            HTTPSRequestCert.cert_request("https://ws020.juntadeandalucia.es/notificaciones/snja/procesaRecepcion.do", client.getCertificateFile().getAbsolutePath(), client.getCertificatePassword(), cookies, "post", Integer.toString(notificationId));
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            Main.insertNotification(notification, client.getCertificateFile().getAbsolutePath(), client.getCertificatePassword(), cookies);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Excepción en getHandler de WebServer");
            Logger.getLogger(WebServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}
```

Solo quería cambiar el parametro `Thread.sleep()` y volver a compilarlo, pero es ahí donde me da el error, se supone que compila bien porque ya existe un .jar que funciona pero que es necesario aplicar el cambio antes mencionado.
Como entorno estoy usando Intellij pero al compilar me borra todos los archivos .class que ya existian en el proyecto que se encontraban en target--> classes-->principal, tambien tengo eclipse.
Por último he usado javac WebServer.java pero me da error como los mencionados anteriormente, como el de package Main doesn´t exist.

Solo quiero modificar el parámetro para que la aplicación vaya mejor.

Comment: Te recomiendo hacer el [tour] y leer [ask] para ver cómo hacer una pregunta correcta. Las imágenes que aportas no añaden mucho a la pregunta en realidad. Da igual que los archivos existan si no los has *importado* correctamente... El error te está diciendo que tienes un problema en la línea 49 del `WebServer.java`, lo más seguro es que ese `Client` que creas no esté correctamente importado. Comprueba que has hecho el correspondiente *import* al inicio del archivo.

Comment: ¿Antes de esa modificación sí te compilaba? Todo parece correcto. ¿Cómo compilas la aplicación? ¿Qué entorno de desarrollo usas? ¿Podrías darnos más datos del proceso de compilación? ¿Podrías compartir la definición de la clase que hay dentro de `Notificacion.java` y `Client.java`?

Comment: Usando Intellij me parece raro que no te saliera en rojo la línea, ya que lo normal es que lo marque (en este IDE en concreto). Aparte de Client, también te marca en el de Notification un error similar, que no reconoce. La pregunta no existe ya que solo nos has dado unos errores (a medias) y ya.

Comment: Es una app que me han pedido corregir se supone que si compilaba, estoy usando Intellj pero cuando aplico el cambio al .java y compilo el proyecto, se me borran los .class que ya tenía

Comment: ¿El proyecto como te lo entregan, comprimido? ¿Y se supone que debe compilar **sin errores** o te han entregado dicho proyecto para corregir? Seguramente es lo que comenta Benito, que este mal importado.

Comment: ¿Has probado a compilarlo manualmente? Es decir, ir haciendo un `javac Client.java`, etc hasta que llegues al `WebServer.java`. Es probable que sea algo de configuración de Intellij (en ese caso, no puedo ayudar mucho, no uso ese entorno de desarrollo).

Comment: @OscarGarcia Lo dudo por el error, es algo de código. Ese error es porque esa variable no esta declarada o no la encuentra.

Comment: @ICodeForCaffeine también puede pasar cuando los espacios de nombres o las rutas a las clases no son correctas. Se queja porque no sabe dónde encontrar esas clases, así que las da por no definidas (`symbol: class Notification, error: cannot find symbol`, por ejemplo).

Comment: @OscarGarcia cierto es, pero hasta que no veamos como esta el código toca apostar a que será.

Comment: Estoy completamente de acuerdo contigo. Esto son elucubraciones hasta que comparta algo de código para poder reproducir su problema.

Comment: He añadido mas información, es que seguro que no es difícil pero no había tocado java nunca, entiendo el código pero me falla al compilarlo